# Network Won't Work Even When the Ethernet Cable is Connected

Tags: networking, ethernet

My Rasberry Pi won't connect to the internet.   I know that my Internet setup is good because when I connect the same Ethernet cable to my main laptop is works perfectly.  Please help.

Comment: show us $ifconfig. hopefully youll see the eth device in there. Then run sudo ifup eth0 or whaterver number it is. rerun ifconfig, and see if you have an ipaddress.

Comment: Do you see the lights on the Pi change when the cable is plugged/unplugged?